# persist username value after page refresh in React using local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I am trying to set and retrieve the value of `username` using the local storage. When the page loads, the user should see a heading that says `welcome John`. And when the page reloads, I need the value to persist.

But when I load the page, I get the error message `username is not defined`. This is the code, what am I missing?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const UserHeading = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("john")

  useEffect(() => {
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user)) || [];
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(username, JSON.stringify(user));
  }, [user]);

  console.log(user);

  const userid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user));

  console.log(userid);

  return <h1> Welcome {userid} </h1>;
};

export default UserHeading;
```

Comment: Everything is a bit confused here. `username` is a variable that does not exist. You reference `username`, but it exists no where in your code. It is not initialised. That one probably needs fixing before we can help because it obfuscates your original intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change your component like this   :**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const UserHeading = () => {
const [user, setUser] = useState("john")

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(user)); //changed
  }, [user]);
console.log(user)
  const userid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username')) //changed
  console.log(userid)

  return <h1> Welcome {userid} </h1>;
};
export default UserHeading;
```

Comment: small remark I think you should not read from local storage during render though. From docs: "This also breaks the rules of React because reading mutable data during rendering (which is when you calculate the dependencies) breaks purity of rendering. ". [link](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects) deep dive section

Comment: You're right  ! Actually the best approach to retrieve  objects from localStorage is using a `useEFfect` hook